# Spark Structured Streaming groupByKey on a time Window not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I need to batch my Kafka stream into time windows of 10 minutes each and then run some batch processing on it.

Note: records below have a timestamp field

```
   val records = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokerPool)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .option("startingOffsets", kafkaOffset)
      .load()
```

I add a time window to each record using,

```
.withColumn("window", window($"timing", windowDuration))
```

I created some helper classes like

```
  case class TimingWindow(
      start: java.sql.Timestamp,
      end: java.sql.Timestamp
  )
  case class RecordWithWindow(
      record: MyRecord,
      groupingWindow: TimingWindow
  )
```

Now I have a DF of type [RecordWithWindow]

All this works very well.

Next,

```
metricsWithWindow
  .groupByKey(_.groupingWindow)
  //By grouping, I get several records per time window
  //resulting an object of the below type which I write out to HDFS

  case class WindowWithRecords(
      records: Seq[MyRecord],
      window: TimingWindow
  )
```

Where I examine HDFS,

**Example**:

*Expected* : 
Each WindowWithRecords object having a unique TimingWindow

```
WindowWithRecordsA(TimingWindowA, Seq(MyRecordA, MyRecordB, MyRecordC))
```

*Actual* : 
More than one WindowWithRecords object with the same TimingWindow

```
WindowWithRecordsA(TimingWindowA, Seq(MyRecordA, MyRecordB))
WindowWithRecordsB(TimingWindowA, Seq(MyRecordC))
```

Looks like the groupByKey logic is not working well.

I hope my question is clear. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that the 3 expected elements arrive in the same micro batch? HDFS records are not updated, so for each micro batch, it writes a TimingWindowA record with all the values that arrived in that execution, or none if it doesn't have any.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem:

I was not using an explicit trigger when processing the window. As a result, Spark was creating micro batches as soon as it could, as opposed to doing it at the end of the window.

```
streamingQuery
.writeStream
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(windowDuration))
...
.start
```

This was a result of me misunderstanding Spark documentation.

Note: groupByKey uses the object's hashcode. It is important to make sure that the hashcode of the object is consistent.

Comment: Not sure I get it, the explicit trigger?

Comment: Basically, I added this 

.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(windowDuration))

This forces my whole window to be processed together at once.